# How to send response to react after dispatching action

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, axios

I have an table with a button of buy now

```
<tr>
<td>some more  </td>
         <td>
         <button
              className="btn btn-primary btn-success"
              id="buy-now"
              type="button" onClick={ e => onClick(data) }
            >
              <i className="fa fa-check" />
            </button>
          </td>
</tr>
```

So when it click it send all the tr data to a function below additemtobuy imported from action.js redux

```
const table = () => { 
const onClick = (data) => {
additemtobuy(data)
}
return({
the above table data
})
}
```

In action.js

```
export default const additemtobuy = (data) => { 

//perform some axios operation and add the items to user order table
 await axios.post('/api/order',data)
 .then( res => { 
console.log('items bought')
/*
I can use dispatch to change the state but I want to show some response on the buy now button 
I used state to change the state of the buy now using redux dispatch but it changes the state of all buy-now buttons 
*/

  })

}
```

Can anyone help me in this any suggestion will  helpful

Comment: what is your problem exactly? Is `data` perhaps meant to be `{ data }` ? Do you have a `catch` to show what error you are receiving in case this is an error from the server? Is `data` defined or undefined by the time it reaches your `onClick` function?

Comment: NO my command execute successfully and i can dispatch function but i want to show some response some in button click after all these

Answer (score 0):

You should identify buttons with unique id. For instance, if you create local state inside `table` component, it will be possible to tracked clicked buttons and render them with different styles with css selector `tr.clicked #buy-now`. Of course, using `clicked` state you can edit not only classname, but any attributes, properties and et al.

```js
const table = () => { 
    const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState({});
    const onClick = (data, id) => { 
        additemtobuy(data);
        setClicked(c=>{
            c.id = true;
            return {...c};
        })
    }
    return(
            <tr className={clicked['some-identifier'] ? 'clicked' : '' }>
            <td>some more  </td>
            <td>
            <button
                className="btn btn-primary btn-success"
                id="buy-now"
                type="button" onClick={ e => onClick(data, 'some-identifier') }
                >
                <i className="fa fa-check" />
                </button>
            </td>
    </tr>
    ) 
}
```

Your special style

```css
tr.clicked #buy-now {
  background-color: red;
}
```